# Automatic form generation software

Tags: sql-server, winforms, forms, code-generation

I'm using winforms. I spend a lot of time drawing forms (maybe not a lot, but it is a boring task).

To sum up... I want to develop a simple aplication that connect to a sql server database, let the user to select a table, and put the controls in a form for me (generate the designer code), based on the tipe of each column. Then my app will name each control like the column of the table, set the maxlengh property (if the type is varchar), and create a label with the same text near the control. If the column is a FK, then the app will draw a combobox and so on. I saw that Telerik Open ORM make something like this, but I only need a simple app for the IU Generation.

If the same day I finish my little application I discover a tool that make the same... I will feel myself stupid :D

Are there any tool out there that do this work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just drag DB columns from the Server Panel and drop them on the Form. This will generate TextField, CheckBoxes and other UI elements for you.

You can also drag the entire table and drop it on the form. Same thing will happen: all fields will get generated.

This is using plan Visual Studio 2008 IDE.

Comment: I'm using VS2008 profesional. I'm triying to do what you tell me, but I Can't drop the table or the fields in the Form... ¿Any Advice? Thanks.

Comment: Well, ppl in with my same situation, please take a look to the first answer in the Q about the same topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058891/auto-generate-vb-net-forms-using-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/) - they have a number of ways to do exactly this. (We're a happy user of their product.)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Microsoft lightswitch. I had posted a similar question as yours and stumbled upon it by accident. Devexpress also has an orm like Teleriks http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Index/Frameworks.xml. I am using Lightswitch for form gen. good luck